# Yii: Getting distinct field values from a related model using scopes

Tags: php, yii, scopes

I'm working on the Admin view in Yii for my Project model.

One of the columns with a filter is user (owner) of the project.

I can do something like this:

```
'filter'=> CHtml::dropDownList('Project[user_id]', $model->user_id,
    CHtml::listData(User::model()->orderAsc()->findAll(),
    'id','username'),array('empty'=>'(select)')),
```

Which gives me a list of all users in the user table, but I'd like to create something that pulls the distinct users who own a project (I've got 200 users, but only a handful tend to create projects).

Project and User are related via:

```
'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id')
```

I've tried a bunch of option in the findAll() method, but none worked, I'm not trying to do something with a scope.

So far I've tried this:

```
'filter'=> CHtml::dropDownList('Project[user_id]', $model->user_id,
    CHtml::listData(Project::model()->with('user')->ownerUsernames()->
    findAll(), 'id','username'),array('empty'=>'(select)')),
```

and my Scope is defined as:

```
'ownerUsernames' => array(
    'with' => 'user.username',
    'select' => 'user.username',
    'distinct' => true,
),
```

I've tried so many iterations of the above I've lost count 'with'=>'username' 'select'=>'username' etc., but just can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried replace Project::model() with $model just because I thought it might have something to do with it, but no luck.

Any ideas are appreciated. Very new to Yii, but this seems like something it can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have everything ready. Define for the project model a getter function like

```
public function getUsername()
{
return $this->user->name;
}
```

Now you should be able to use

```
CHtml::dropDownList('Project[user_id]', $model->user_id,
    CHtml::listData(Project::model()->with('user')->ownerUsernames()->
    findAll(), 'id','username'),array('empty'=>'(select)'))
```

The logic is that CHtml::listData will get the projects as a model, it will create the keys using $project->id and it will create the values using $project->username. Because you created the getted function it will know what $project->username is. Unfortunately CHtml::listData(Project::model()->with('user')->ownerUsernames()->findAll(), 'id','user.name') will not work because it cannot execute 'user.name' or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

actually you can do many things to accomplish that but some methods would be not appropriate due to time consumption. I prefer to tackle this problem as

1. Make a table in DB named user_project with attributes
   id
   user_id(fk to user table)
   project_id(fk to project table)
2. When you create a project then also populate user_project with given fields.
3. Make its model and you will see relations in it. Now make a function like

> ```
> public function getName()
> {
> return user->name;//here i have assumed that the relation name is user
> }
> ```

- Now query this table like

> ```
> $user=UserProject::mode::findAll();
> $list=CHtml::listData($user,'user_id','name');
> ```

and use this list to populate the dropDownList. The benefit of this method is that you dont need to query all users of the user table.

Comment: I believe you can also do $list=CHtml::listData($user,'user_id','name'); because you defined getName and that is a getter.